# Ensure that a class is not abstract

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, abstract-class, typechecking

When I change the signature of a virtual method, it happens quite frequently, that inheriting classes become abstract. This might lead to (confusingly large) error messages at apparently completely unrelated (to the original change) locations. Somewhere in these messages, I read "Foo is abstract". But parsing these error messages is tedious. Is there a way to enforce that a class is *not* abstract?

Comment: Design changes often create large ripples. You should try to stabilize the interface early, to avoid this sort of problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to specify that a method in the derived class overrides the abstract method in the base class. When you change the signature of the method in the base class, the `override` specified method should cause a clear compiler error because because it no longer overrides the base class method.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the keyword `override` is here since C++11 and thus you will need to enable it in the compiler if it is not implicit.

Comment: No problem with that. I was fixated on the properties of the class. It just never occurred to me that it could be a property of the method.